# Facebook app keeps crashing on Genymotion emulator

Tags: android, facebook, genymotion

I have got the Genymotion installed in my ubuntu 12.10 system recently. And have installed the ARM Translation and GApps (followed [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2528952) link ) . After setting up the google play store app, I have installed the latest facebook app to the genymotion emulator. Now when I open the facebook app, it keeps on crashing. Any possible fixes for this issue? Will this be an issue of genymotion or facebook app?

Comment: What Android OS Version are you using for the EMulator Image? Are yoiu able to download and run other apps from the play store?

Comment: Im using Android version 4.3 OS. Yes, I have downloaded twitter app from play store and it works perfect without any issues.

Comment: @NavyaRamesan I think its the issue of Genymotion, not the facebook app.

Comment: Try Andro VM cheers,it works facebook perfectly here

Comment: @Pratik: Even I thought so, wanted to know if anyone out there has faced the same issue and if they have somehow fixed this. Thanks.

Comment: @NavyaRamesan is it necessary to use genymotion for you?

Comment: @Pratik: No. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @NavyaRamesan solution is just create android avd from avd manager or just use device , because users will not use that app on genymotion or on emulator, they just use real device.

Comment: @Pratik : Android AVD is quite slow which makes my system also slow. So I'm looking for a better AVD with a better performance.

Comment: @NavyaRamesan yah that's true, I agree, but in Genymotion is depends on lots of things Navya, like OS version, SDK version etc.

Comment: Any luck getting the solution?